# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 when Compiling Swift Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

[image: compiler crash]

I want to make a Tetris Game Project in iOS. But I am facing this problem in this picture. The Xcode occur this ERROR, I couldn't fix it. I used to think, a Shape class has 7 of different Shape subclasses and I divided them in 8 files included the Shape class, that may occur this ERROR. Then I put all of them in one file. However, It occur again.

Here is some of my codes:

```
class Shape: Hashable, CustomStringConvertible{
    let color: BlockColor

    var blocks = Array<Block>()
    var orientation: Orientation
    var column: Int = 0
    var row: Int = 0

    // 每个块中的每个小块的位置
    var blockColRowPositions: [Orientation: Array<(col: Int, row: Int)>]{
        return [:]
    }
    // 每个块在底部的形状
    var bottomBlocksForOrientations: [Orientation: Array<Block>]{
        return [:]
    }


    var bottomBlock: Array<Block>{
        guard let bottomBlocks = bottomBlocksForOrientations[orientation] else{
            return []
        }
        return bottomBlocks
    }

    var hashValue:Int{
        return blocks.reduce(0) {$0.hashValue ^ $1.hashValue}
    }

    var description:String{
        return "\(color) block facing \(orientation) : \(blocks[firstIndex]), \(blocks[secondIndex]), \(blocks[thirdIndex]), \(blocks[forthIndex])"
    }

// ....

}
```

```
class O_Shape: Shape {

    // 每个块中的每个小块的位置
    override var blockColRowPositions: [Orientation: Array<(column: Int, row: Int)>] {
        return [
            Orientation.zero:       [(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)],
            Orientation.twoQuater:  [(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)],
            Orientation.fourQuater: [(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)],
            Orientation.sixQuater:  [(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)]
        ]
    }

    override var bottomBlocksForOrientations: [Orientation: Array<Block>] {
        return[
            Orientation.zero:       [blocks[thirdIndex], blocks[forthIndex]],
            Orientation.twoQuater:  [blocks[thirdIndex], blocks[forthIndex]],
            Orientation.fourQuater: [blocks[thirdIndex], blocks[forthIndex]],
            Orientation.sixQuater:  [blocks[thirdIndex], blocks[forthIndex]]
        ]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture suggests it is crashing during the compilation. This used to be a fairly common occurrence with Swift but is less so now.

The first thing you should o is make sure you are on the latest version of Xcode, which is 7.2.1.

If the compilation crash is still happening, you might be able to fix the problem by finding out which line of code causes the crash. I used to do this by commenting out the whole file and then uncommenting bits one by one until it causes the crash.

Then you need to find a way of rewriting the code so as to avoid the crash and you also need to send a bug report to Apple @ https://bugreport.apple.com. It doesn't matter what code you throw at it, the compiler should not crash, if your code is wrong, it should produce an error message.

Comment: First, thank you answer my question. I've already done the what you recommend. When I was commenting the codes of subclass, the Question was resolved. But what I need are those codes of subclass. With out those subclass. I have to think other way to add new shape in my Tetris Game. I think making a subclass to inherit the SHAPE class is very natural. Could you order any other ways to solve it, please? I will thank you very much.

Comment: @朱晨希 Which bits in the subclasses actually cause the crash?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to read the crash message. I commented every subclass, and each subclass can cause the crash.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you can read the crash message. Try uncommenting one of the classes but commenting everything inside and then uncommenting each thing inside until you get the crash.

Comment: I try it for those day, finally, I changed the dictionary symbol '[ ]' to 'Dictionary<>'. After I changed it, the crash was disappeared. All in all, thank you for help.

Comment: Great. This is a bug in the compiler that you you should report to Apple.

Comment: Hi, after that, I figure out the most original crash is the column and row names in type 'Array<>'. if I change the names of those, such as 'colDiff' and 'rowDiff'. The crash was gone.